# Hiding rows in the UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

How can I configure my tableview below to reflect only the rows with an unhidden cell? Here's the code for the view controller with the tableview in question:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let post = posts[indexPath.row]
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("favorCell") as? FavorCell {
          cell.configureCell(post)
          cell.hidePost(post)
          return cell
    } else {
        return FavorCell()
    }
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return posts.count
}
```

And this is the function in my TableViewCell for hiding the cell:

```
func hidePost(post: Post){  
    self.post = post
    if post.username != uid {
        self.hidden = true
    }  
}
```

Comment: You need to manage it from numberOfRowsInSection

Comment: Don't hide cells, rather create another array based on your `posts` array that only includes the unhidden posts and use that array to drive your tableview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make two array and use according to your condition and after any updation reload your table.

Ex:

```
if(is_searching == true) {
      cell.textLabel?.text = Array1[indexPath.row]["xyz"] as! NSString as String
      cell.accessoryView?.hidden = true

 }
 else {
       cell.textLabel?.text = Array2[indexPath.row]["xyz"] as! NSString as String 
 }
```

Don't Forget to reload your table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `heightForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method and then return 0 for the cells whose corresponding data model hidden is true.